# How do I write the try-catch properly in my google-cloud-function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, try-catch

I'm trying to firebase deploy this function from [Flutter chat app extended — push notification messages](https://medium.com/@duytq94/flutter-chat-app-extended-push-notification-messages-a26c669f4675) Guide on medium.com. I've copy/pasted it on but get these errors and warnings in return. I've been trying to add the try-catch statements, but it stills fails. Can anyone help me?

```
   7:29  warning  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  consistent-return
  19:9   error    Expected catch() or return                               promise/catch-or-return
  24:17  error    Each then() should return a value or throw               promise/always-return
  29:17  error    Expected catch() or return                               promise/catch-or-return
  29:17  warning  Avoid nesting promises                                   promise/no-nesting
  34:25  error    Each then() should return a value or throw               promise/always-return
  46:23  warning  Avoid nesting promises                                   promise/no-nesting
  46:23  warning  Avoid nesting promises                                   promise/no-nesting
  49:31  error    Each then() should return a value or throw               promise/always-return
```

The function.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
  .document('messages/{groupId1}/{groupId2}/{message}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    console.log('----------------start function--------------------')

    const doc = snap.data()
    console.log(doc)

    const idFrom = doc.idFrom
    const idTo = doc.idTo
    const contentMessage = doc.content

    // Get push token user to (receive)
    admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .where('id', '==', idTo)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(userTo => {
          console.log(`Found user to: ${userTo.data().nickname}`)
          if (userTo.data().pushToken && userTo.data().chattingWith !== idFrom) {
            // Get info user from (sent)
            admin
              .firestore()
              .collection('users')
              .where('id', '==', idFrom)
              .get()
              .then(querySnapshot2 => {
                querySnapshot2.forEach(userFrom => {
                  console.log(`Found user from: ${userFrom.data().nickname}`)
                  const payload = {
                    notification: {
                      title: `You have a message from "${userFrom.data().nickname}"`,
                      body: contentMessage,
                      badge: '1',
                      sound: 'default'
                    }
                  }
                  // Let push to the target device
                  admin
                    .messaging()
                    .sendToDevice(userTo.data().pushToken, payload)
                    .then(response => {
                      console.log('Successfully sent message:', response)
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                      console.log('Error sending message:', error)
                    })
                })
              })
          } else {
            console.log('Can not find pushToken target user')
          }
        })
      })
    return null
  })
```

Comment: At the highest level, study JavaScript Promises.  Every time you use a promise you will have a then() handler which is executed when the promise is fulfilled.  However, if the promise fails, you need a catch() handler.  Quickly eyeballing your code, not all Promises have catch() handlers.

Comment: Alright.. I'll try if I can fix this :)

Comment: Each one of those error message can be searched for, and you can get an explanation of what they mean. You will definitely need to understand JavaScript promises in order to write effective Cloud Functions code.

Comment: but I'm throwing an catch at each then.. so I cant see why it still fails

Comment: Okay ive found the places where i missed the .catch-parts.. now I only have 3 errors, "Each then() should return a value or throw " how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got everything working:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
  .document('messages/{groupId1}/{groupId2}/{message}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    console.log('----------------start function--------------------')

    const doc = snap.data()
    console.log(doc)

    const idFrom = doc.idFrom
    const idTo = doc.idTo
    const contentMessage = doc.message

    // Get push token user to (receive)
    admin.firestore().collection('users').where('uid', '==', idTo).get().then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(userTo => {
          console.log(`Found user to: ${userTo.data().uid}`)
          if (userTo.data().pushToken) {
            // Get info user from (sent)
            admin.firestore().collection('users').where('uid', '==', idFrom).get().then(querySnapshot2 => {

                querySnapshot2.forEach(userFrom => {
                  console.log(`Found user from: ${userFrom.data().uid}`)
                  const payload = {
                    notification: {
                      title: `You have a message from "${userFrom.data().uid}"`,
                      body: contentMessage,
                      badge: '1',
                      sound: 'default'
                    }
                  }
                  // Let push to the target device

                  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userTo.data().pushToken, payload).then(response => {
                  return console.log('Successfully sent message:', response)


                    }).catch(error => {
                      console.log('Error sending message:', error)
                    })

                })
                return console.log('failed')
              }).catch(error => {
                 console.log('Error sending message:', error)
              })
          } else {
            console.log('Can not find pushToken target user')
          }
        })
        return console.log('error: invalid path')
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error)
      })




    return null
  })
```